# What's the target number when you don't have a relevant focus?

Tags: age-system, the-expanse-rpg

How much does the target number go up if a PC doesn't have a relevant focus? The rules mention that the GM decides if they're allowed to roll at all, but doesn't mention target number.

The example in the book (p102) has Miller investigating a martial arts dojo:

- If he has the **primary focus** of Communication (Persuasion), the TN is standard. Let's say that's a TN of 11.
- If he doesn't have the primary focus, but has a **tangential focus**, such as Communication (Bargaining) or Communication (Deception) or Fighting (Brawling), then the TN is +2. So that makes the TN 13.
- If he has the **Improvisation Talent** (p53) he can do things as if he always has the tangential focus, so TN 13 again.

Is the TN still 13 if he has no tangential focuses (foci) and doesn't have Improvisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The rules don't say, so the GM decides

As you pointed out, a tangential focus explicitly adds +2 to the TN (if an ability check is required). Additionally, if you don't have a primary or tangential focus (p. 102):

> the GM decides whether you can make a test to unlock the lead at all

The rules don't give any additional guidance about the lack of a primary or tangential focus for an investigation. So, **how should an investigation's target number be determined?**

For a Simple Investigation where the GM has determined that a roll is required (p. 100):

> Succeed on an ability test **against a TN set by the GM**, and you get the information you need.

For a Detailed Investigation where the GM has determined that a roll is required (p. 101):

> Most commonly, unlocking a lead requires a character to succeed at an ability test. [...] **The GM determines** [...] **the TN of the test**.

Neither type of investigation gives further guidance about determining an appropriate TN, so we are left with **the GM determines the TN**.

## What TN should the GM use?

Assuming the GM determines that a test *can* be made, what would be a reasonable TN? Two possibilities come to mind (given a base TN 11):

1. **TN 13 Ability test (with no focus).** There is no applicable focus, so just use the most-applicable ability. This effectively increases the TN by 2, given the lack of a +2 from a focus.
2. **TN 15 Ability (Focus) test.** There is no primary or tangential focus, so just use the most-applicable one. The test is made another step (+2) harder, on top of the +2 from not having a primary focus. This is numerically the same as the first option, though different character Traits may apply.

If you instead keep a TN 13 test *with* a focus, then you're effectively giving everyone (a large part of) the Improvisation Talent, which probably won't feel great for players who chose that. Even though target numbers are a core part of the game, The Expanse RPG leaves a lot up to the GM, so the real (somewhat unhelpful) answer is: **pick whatever TN you feel makes sense**.